# How to Maximize window in chrome using webDriver (python)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Is there a way to maximize the chrome browser window using python selenium WebDriver?

Note: I am using Chrome Driver 23.0
Any solution on this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 134, accepted):

You could use ChromeOptions and set suitable argument:

```
options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
driver = ChromeDriver(options)
```

Comment: not working for me - the window snapshot show that the size is only 800x600

Comment: @NamGVU check what's the actual screen resolution while executing test - the maximum size is the size of the resolution. I had this problem some time ago because of test being run by process executed as a service. This caused process to be run in Session 0, which has limited capabilities when it comes to screen resolution. Running tests not in a services solves that issue.

Comment: I run it on ubuntu server; so i guess the screen size set by Xvfb. Thanks to point it out.

Comment: This is 2017/12/15 now. `driver.fullscreen_window()` works.

Comment: **driver.maximize_window()** is more comfortable function that works with **selenium chrome driver** in **python**.

Comment: This is July 2022, the last comment code works, driver.maximize_window() please credit it.

Comment: Just want to add, that in my case adding the --window-size and the --start-maximized argument causes the  --start-maximized to fail. When I removed the --window-size, the window now starts maximized

Answer (score 63):

Nothing worked for me except:

```
driver.set_window_size(1024, 600)
driver.maximize_window()
```

I found this by inspecting selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py. I've never found any useful documentation, but reading the code has been marginally effective.

Comment: This is a better answer than the other ones since this one supports all browsers and not just Chrome.

Comment: You don't actually need to set the window size first.

Comment: For me, `maximize_window` had no effect. Not doing `set_window_size` kept the window at 800x600, `set_window_size(1920, 1080)` before calling `maximize_window` and when not calling `maximize_window` made the window size 1920x1080. `fullscreen_window` caused my code to hang. I'm using Chrome with `options.add_argument("--headless")`.

Answer (score 48):

Based on what Janek answered, this worked for me (Linux):

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

Comment: This didn't work for me on Linux at first, but updated the Chrome driver with `sudo apt install chromium-chromedriver` and it worked then.

Comment: `webdriver.Chrome(options=options)`

Answer (score 47):

For MAC or Linux:

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.addArguments("--kiosk");
driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

For Windows:

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.addArguments("--start-maximized");
driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

Comment: Question is specifically for python.

Comment: --kiosk is only one that worked for me on Mac. Thanks.

Comment: Keep in mind that once using `--kiosk`, trying to change window size will crash the driver, example (python): `opts = webdriver.ChromeOptions();
opts.add_argument('--kiosk'); driver = ChromeDriver(chrome_options=opts); driver.set_window_size(800, 600)`. Either fullscreen or windowed.

Answer (score 16):

Try this:

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

Comment: i am using driver.window_maximize().but it doesn't work for chrome browser alone.

Comment: **AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'manage'**

Comment: yeah, this answer is old.

Answer (score 8):

This works for me, with Mac OS Sierra using Python,

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--kiosk")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

Answer (score 7):

I do the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:\chromedriver.exe')
browser.maximize_window()
```

Answer (score 5):

try this, tested on windows platform and it works fine :

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\\yeivic\\Downloads\\chromedriver')
browser.fullscreen_window()
browser.get('http://google.com/')
```

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--start-fullscreen");
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Question is specifically for Python

Answer (score 3):

this works for me

```
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)
```